# Google Mail Filter neverSpam

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I have a PHP application that sends emails through gmail. The emails are sent when website events occur, for example, the contact form. However, the emails are put in the spam folder of the recipient. Some recipients of this email are in gmail, and others are in outlook, and others are in yahoo.

Will the

name="neverSpam"

affect the sending of emails, so the recipients will not see it in the spam folder?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems this is happening because the recipient may not be a member of the sender's contact list, a security measure. Here's a note from [Gmail Help](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/9008?hl=en):

> If you find that some senders' messages are consistently being
>   mislabeled as spam, you can prevent this by:
>
> 'Adding their email addresses to your Contacts list. Gmail will
>   deliver messages from members of your Contacts list to your inbox,
>   unless we know with high confidence that they are spam'

[neverSpam](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/email-settings/#java) is a boolean for Filter Action Properties. If you want to make sure your message is not tagged as spam, add the recipients to your contacts list.